# Why would travelling hyperspace kill Frog Lady's eggs?

Tags: star-wars, hyperspace, the-mandalorian

In S02E02 the Mandalorian gives a ride to a Frog Lady. However they have to travel at sub-light speed, because apparently, travelling at hyperspeed would kill her eggs. It is not explained further and feels like really lazy writing. I can't think of any plausible reason why would the hyperspeed kill the eggs. Is there a canon or legends explanation for that?

Comment: How many decades to the destination?

Comment: @PeterM Insignificant, apparently. Maybe a couple of days, judging from the episode. (sub-light can still be something like .9c). In the episode, they mention a couple times that the destination is "the next sector over". I don't know how big a sector is in Star Wars, or where in its sector Tatooine lies (e.g. the edge vs the middle).

Comment: More or less than 12 parsecs?

Comment: at sublight speeds you can reach any other point in arbitrarily short amounts of proper time (i.e. time as experienced by the traveller). The issue is that, because of relativity, the rest of the universe experiences a lot more time, and what Din experiences as a couple of days could potentially be decades or more for the people at the destination. Of course whether relativity exists in Star Wars, and how hyperspace actually interacts with what we know about relativity is another matter

Comment: @TylerH https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/how-long-would-a-near-light-speed-trip-to-proxima-centauri-take-from-the-travele Even going to the next star (from Earth) at .9c, you've got about 2 years subjective or 4 years as viewed from Earth. Also, we're assuming you don't take any time accelerating or decelerating.

Comment: And if you're going *very* close to light speed, then why is the Death Star so impressive? Everyone else is already whizzing around in "planet buster" relativistic space ships. https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/ And no one has a "drunk flying" problem twice.

Comment: @user3067860 Star Wars isn't famous for its continuity. Anyway, a sector could be just 'part of a solar system'; it doesn't necessarily have to be interstellar. You'd have to find some canon info on sectors in Star Wars to confirm.

Comment: @TylerH "[A sector was defined by the Republic as having a maximum of 50 inhabited star systems to keep sectors at a manageable level.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sector/Legends)".  By that definition worst case scenario is you have to cross on average 25 star systems, and best case a single star over.  All of which by Einsteinian physics is not just "a couple of days".  I know, I know I shouldn't bring science to a fictional show.

Comment: @PeterM The quote *is* valuable to bring into the discussion, however :-) It shows that a sector is most likely to be multiple star systems, which means there is definitely some time fudging going on... unless they just want viewers to assume several years passed on that tiny ship...

Comment: @user3067860 - Because even the poorest planet has a basic planetary shield that prevents near-lightspeed accidents.

Comment: It always bothered me when ANY science fiction show/movie has some situation where a ship has to travel from one place to another (outside it's own star system) without using faster than light travel, and yet somehow they can still arrive in only days or weeks, instead of decades or centuries....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In canon there's something called [*'Cronau radiation'*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cronau_radiation) which was emitted by spaceships when they jumped to and from hyperspace.

> The specialist at the station thrust his head forward.
>
> “Sir, sensors are registering anomalous readings and Cronau radiation in the red zone—”
>
> “Wake rotation!” another spec cut in. “We’ve got a mark in from hyperspace, sir—and it’s a big one.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Tarkin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))</sup></sub>

The frog lady's eggs might be vulnerable to this in particular, or other types of radiation which most organisms can ignore.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing a canon quote from the Tarkin novel which mentions Cronau radiation.

Comment: A good find. The young of most species are usually quite susceptible to radiation injury.

Comment: Out of canon, I'm pretty sure jumping past or dropping below lightspeed would produce what we know as Cherenkov radiation. Possibly the same thing, since they wouldn't have named it after Pavel Cherenkov

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat keep in mind that you can not break the light speed barrier in vacuum. Cherenkov radiation will only be observed in medium where c < c_0

Comment: @infinitezero - Sublight speeds in Star Wars are limited by something called "ether" which acts as a dragging force. You need to continually accelerate and ships have a "top speed" limited not by fuel or acceleration but shielding and fuel consumption.

Comment: Well, mixing Earth science and Star Wars science is not something one should do, but in that case I  think it's another point against Cherenkov radiation.